# Selenium with Python: how to select a tag inside elements with a known class

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Selenium with **Python**

Could you help me select all elements with a tag "b" inside spans with class "extended_text__full".

Please, have a look at the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below xapth to get all b tag inside desired span tag:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='extended-text_full']/b");
```